# org.apache.cordova.file-transfer how to abort download file

Tags: cordova, file-transfer, cordova-3

Suppose the connection on mobile is weak and gets stuck, how can I interrupt a file transfer in progress before the loading spinner digs a hole on the screen?

doc here https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md#abort

According to documentation use of the abort() method should do it, but looks like no way. Both iOS and Android. Download function works. However the abort don't do anything. The file is downloaded  after the abort() call, anyway. Even after 10 seconds.

I have:

```
function downloadMyFilePlease () {

var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/download.php");

fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
        //...
                                                        };

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    }
);

}

function abortFileTrasfer () { // called on Abort button click

    fileTransfer.abort(); // <------ Why are you not working??? 
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Variable fileTransfer isn't defined inside `abortFileTrasfer()` function, it's a local variable inside `downloadMyFilePlease()`, so you can't access it in `abortFileTrasfer()`.

Comment: Thanks, I had that feeling. Well, I think there will not be other file transfers at the same time. So do you think that bringing the var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer(); right before the function, will be safe and fix it? Or there is another better solution?

Comment: @sasha, yes, I believe it will work, but don't forget to remove `fileTransfer` from memory when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: for removing `fileTransfer` what's the best way? `fileTransfer.destroy()` or `fileTransfer = []` can't find clear answer. Sorry for this question but not used to this JS level coding.

Comment: I believe you just need to do `fileTransfer = null;`.
This way you'll remove the link to the resource => there will be no variables linking to this resource and the Garbage Collector then removes it from memory.